# Simple Control Panel webpage on RedHat server is not responding

Tags: linux, apache-2.2

At some point, attempting to access my Simple Control Panel webpage worked, but now the page (https://my-ip-address:9999) just hangs and then I get a Webpage Unavailable error.  I'm thinking that potentially I overwrote an important piece of code in the /etc/httpd/conf.d/turbopanel.conf, or /etc/httpd/conf.d/turbopanel-ssl.conf.  The turbopanel-ssl.conf is below:

```
NameVirtualHost my-ip-address:443

<VirtualHost my-ip-address:443>
ServerName mydomain
DocumentRoot "/path/to/main/website"
<Directory "/path/to/main/website">
    Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>

SSLEngine on
SSLCACertificateFile "/var/turbopanel/certs/0/Cert0.ca"
SSLCertificateFile "/var/turbopanel/certs/0/Cert0.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "/var/turbopanel/certs/0/Cert0.key"
Alias /usage "/path/to/main/usage"
<Location /usage>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

I have a virtual dedicated server with godaddy running Red Hat Fedora Core 7.  What are the best ways to troubleshoot this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The config is telling it to serve on port 443, you're looking for it on port 9999.

Try https://my-ip-address or https://my-ip-address:443

Answer (score 0):

I apologize - it turns out that building our office is located in recently set up some sort of firewall that blocks certain ports (read: most).  I had tested out different computers/browsers/etc. but didn't find out until I attempted to access it from home after work.  Sorry!